# Return Value %eax Convention

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention

Naturally in i386, the %eax holds the return value of functions, yes?  However apparently this is only convention.  Is it possible to change this convention, and make the return value be %ebx or something?  And if you were to do this, would this also make %ebx return values to the system?

Comment: I might add that calling conventions are usually covered in an application binary interface (ABI), if you look at different conventions you might figure out if you can change what your system uses for an exit status but i'm not so sure if it's even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is convention only, yes. Since the `ret` instruction doesn't change any registers except `esp`, you can use any other to return values. However both the caller and the callee have to agree on where the return value should be, so if you want to interoperate with other code, the calling conventions used must be compatible. Between your own functions, you can use whatever you want. Compilers also invent ad-hoc conventions for private functions for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but how do you use different registers for return values in code?  When ret executes, it puts the return value into %eax regardless.  Do you have to change the conventions at compile time, or can you write your own conventions, and if so, how?

Comment: As I said, `ret` does not change registers except `esp`. As such it does not place anything in `eax`. The called function puts the return value in `eax` (or wherever you want) and `ret` does not touch it or care about it. `ret` is barely more than a glorified `jmp`. The caller has to look in the right place. Yes, this is a compile-time thing.